# Calculate Average kph from int variable and a timespan variable

Tags: vb.net

I have a variable which is an integer and another which is a timespan.
The integer is the kilometres and the timespan is the Time Taken to complete so on and so on...

I think it's something like (distance / time taken) but I can't do that so easily. 
I would like to get kph from the two variables and put the result into a label.

My results I get from my variables will be like this:
e.g.
13 (km) and 00:25:12 (Time Taken)

Can you help me with a solution please :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are looking for kilometers *per* hour (k/h), you need to divide your kilometers (13) by the total hours (0.42).  You can get the total hours from the `TimeSpan` object by reading it's `TotalHours` property, for instance:

```
Dim span As New TimeSpan(0, 25, 12)
Dim distance As Integer = 13
Dim speed As Double = distance / span.TotalHours
```

Comment: Hi there :) This time you were faster.

Comment: Clearly you've got this.  I can take the afternoon off :)

Comment: Haha, sometimes it's pure joy to sit back and watch the "battle" on SO:p

Comment: If you are getting infinity, that means your `Race_Time` is probably zero.  How are you setting that?

Comment: Ok it's all good now. My stupidity made me use this code before `Race_Time` had even been assigned a value yet :D Thanks guys ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Yes, kph is km/hours, so this is the code you are looking for:

```
    Dim ts = New TimeSpan(0, 25, 12)
    Dim distance = 13
    Dim kph = distance / ts.TotalHours
```

Spoler alert! Your a driving at 30.95 kph.